# Dividing a list into groups ithat contiain equal amount of elements - in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, grouping

So I have a list that contins about 1400 elements. What I want to do is dividing elements into groups each containing 7 elements in order. How can I do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14]
[lst[i:i + 7] for i in range(0, len(lst), 7)]

#output
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]]
```

Comment: Please look for duplicates before answering. Questions like this have usually been asked and answered on SO many times before.

Comment: think you want `sorted(lst[i:i + 7])` based on the description but not 100%.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi if a question closes as duplicate, can you get points for that 'answer'?

Comment: @Carbon you don't get points for voting to close. You keep points from any upvotes or downvotes to an actual answer, but those get taken away if the question is deleted